# How to fix Xcode 10 GM error while building my SDK Aggregate Project with New Build System?

Tags: ios, armv7, xcode10, swift4.2

I am trying to build my project and I got this below errors ..could anyone have a fix?

Xcode: Xcode 10 GM, swift: 4.2, deployment target:iOS 10.3

[image]

thanks in advance...